Qt 5.15.2 QML mapbox issue: tile request error "Problem with tile image"
I am trying to use mapbox in QML since I need a satellite map where I would put some markers (pins). I didn't have any issue loading a map with osm plugin, but osm doesn't offer satellite so I tried with mapbox and I get a bunch of these errors:
W libAppName_x86_64.so: tile request error "Problem with tile image"
W libAppName_x86_64.so: tile request error "Problem with tile image"
W libAppName_x86_64.so: tile request error "Problem with tile image"
W libAppName_x86_64.so: tile request error "Problem with tile image"
W libAppName_x86_64.so: tile request error "Problem with tile image"
W libAppName_x86_64.so: tile request error "Problem with tile image"
The number of errors depend on the initial zoom (bigger zoom, lower number of errors) and they happen if I try to move the map to another coordinates.
I tried looking for an answer everywhere, but I can't find somebody with the same issue as me. I have been stuck with this for a few weeks and I would appreciate if somebody has any idea.
Here is a part of my code:
 Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "mapbox"

        PluginParameter {
            name: "mapbox.access_token";
            value: "<valid token>"
        }
    }

    Map {
        id: mapview
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(41.943243, 21.576327)
        zoomLevel: 14
        activeMapType: mapview.supportedMapTypes[10]

        MapItemView{
            model: markerModel
            delegate: mapcomponent
        }
    }

